# I am not able to access Date column while reading data from Alphavantage api

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to use AlphaVantage API to get data into dataframe and use in Plotly dash. I am able to see data, but not able to read Date column in plotly.
please help.

```
import pandas as pd
import configparser
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objs  as go
import plotly.express as px
import datetime

parser = configparser.RawConfigParser()
parser.read('config_key.ini')
info = parser['apikey']['key']

ts = TimeSeries(key=info,output_format='pandas', indexing_type='date')
data, meta_data = ts.get_daily(symbol='AAPL', outputsize='full')
data.rename(columns={'date':'Date','1. open': 'open', '2. high': 'high',
                     '3. low': 'low', '4. close': 'close', '5. volume': 'volume'},
            inplace=True)
data.sort_values(by='date', ascending=False, inplace=True)

data.head()
[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The date of the acquired data frame is indexed, so it will be `data.index` instead of `data['date']`. Since I am not using the config parser, the code changes the way we get the API information.

```
import pandas as pd
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

with open('./alpha_vantage_api_key.txt') as f:
    api_key = f.read()

ts = TimeSeries(key=api_key, output_format='pandas', indexing_type='date')
data, meta_data = ts.get_daily(symbol='AAPL', outputsize='full')
data.rename(columns={'date':'Date','1. open': 'open', '2. high': 'high',
                     '3. low': 'low', '4. close': 'close', '5. volume': 'volume'},
            inplace=True)
data.sort_values(by='date', ascending=False, inplace=True)

data.head()
            open    high    low     close   volume
date                    
2020-11-20  118.64  118.7700    117.290     117.34  73604287.0
2020-11-19  117.59  119.0600    116.810     118.64  74112972.0
2020-11-18  118.61  119.8200    118.000     118.03  76322111.0
2020-11-17  119.55  120.6741    118.960     119.39  74270973.0
2020-11-16  118.92  120.9900    118.146     120.30  91183018.0

import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=data.index,
                open=data['open'],
                high=data['high'],
                low=data['low'],
                close=data['close'])])

fig.show()
```

[image]